# Define YAML Mapping Recursively

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

Is there a simple way to define a mapping in yaml in such a way that the value is itself defined within the yaml. E.g.

```
alice:
  name: Alice

bob:
  manager: *alice
```

So that the value that mapped to the `mangager` key for `bob` is the `alice` object, not a string. So that once the file is parsed I can do something like

```py
>>> data = yaml.load(file_path)
>>> alice, bob = data["alice"], data["bob"]
>>> bob.manager is alice
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to give the object you want to reference an anchor:

```yaml
alice: &alice
  name: Alice

bob:
  manager: *alice
```